# $ symbol for jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have $ symbol in my javascript file to identify jQuery funcionality. Now I am going to use asp.net ajax in the same file. But this also comes with the $ symbol. Will this cause any serious trouble? If so how can i make things better? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Cut and paste from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Sample usage:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jQuery.noConflict()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jQuery.noConflict()` to enter no conflict mode:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Then use `jQuery` instead of `$` like this: `jQuery(document).ready(...`

Answer (score 0):

It will cause conflicts.Replace Jquery's `$` instances with `jQuery` object.